# Java- Regular Expression to slipt

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm having some problems to find a way to transform a string, that represents a geometry Linestring. The coordinates are displayed in (Lon,Lat) and I want to transform in (Lat,Lon).. 
Example:

`LINESTRING (0 1, 3 2 , 4 5)`

to

`LINESTRING (1 0, 2 3 , 5 4 )`

Is it possible to do with a Regular Expression?
Thanks

Comment: yes it is but what have you tried?

Comment: First I've tried with a for and while, but it's not working..So, as I don't know nothing about regex, I'm trying to see if someone knows some good example for my case..

Comment: why is regex a requirement?

Comment: It's not! Just a guess ..

Answer (score 3):

Without heavy usage of regex,you can achieve the same as follows. I myself don't know much about regex,and hence proposing a simple solution...

Considering about the coordinates, you can do the following :-

```
String a = "0 1, 3 2 , 4 5";
String b[] = a.split(",");
String c[] = new String[b.length];
for (i = 0; i < b.length; b++) {
    c[i] = new StringBuilder(b[i]).reverse().toString();
}
String new = c[0] + "," + c[1] + "," + c[2];
```

Comment: It says that type string cannot use the reverse() function...

Comment: Check my edited code,I forgot to convert from StringBuilder to String,change the second last line to `c[i]=new StringBuilder(b[i]).reverse().toString();`...

Comment: It's not working! My mistake when I said that.. I tested now with real values, like (-9.157465 38.7183154) and it gives me : 4513817.38 564751.9- ... Any idea for a solution?

Comment: @cpfp-This will work only with integers,NOT reals because real numbers involve `.` which won't be resolved using this! You need to apply some trick like not using reverse(),first apply split again on `space` ---`String d[i]=b[i].split(" ");`. Then you should swap the results,VOILA-you got the solution! But,remember it's a tricky part of coding!

Comment: @cpfp-If you have further problem in solving in the aforementioned way,please post a new question and pass me the link over here!

Comment: I've solved, I will post ;)

Comment: result.replaceAll("(\\d+.\\d+) (\\d+.\\d+)", "$2 $1");

  String point[] = result.split(",");
  return point;

Answer (score 2):

If you want to switch places two numbers separated by space you can do it with `replaceAll(regex, replacement)`.
 `regex` representing two numbers separated by space can look like `(\\d+) (\\d+)`

- `\\d` represents one digit (character `0`, `1` ... `9`)
- `\\d+` represents string build from one or more digits
- `(\\d+)` will place match from `\\d+` in group which will let us reuse it later

Now because each number is in separate [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) we can use matches from this groups in `replacement` via `$x` where `x` represents group number, so in this case we can put match from group 2 before match from group 1.

Demo:

```
String text = "LINESTRING (0 1, 3 2 , 4 5)";
System.out.println("before replacing: "+text);

text = text.replaceAll("(\\d+) (\\d+)", "$2 $1");
System.out.println("after replacing: "+text);
```

Output:

```
before replacing: LINESTRING (0 1, 3 2 , 4 5)
after replacing: LINESTRING (1 0, 2 3 , 5 4)
```

Comment: It's a shame because I can't give you the right answer! It works great.